# What do the attention weights returned by torch_geometric.nn.conv.GATConv represent?

Tags: attention-model, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

```py
class GAT(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels, out_channels, num_heads, dropout=0.3):
        super(GAT, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.conv1 = GATConv(in_channels, hidden_channels, heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout)
        self.conv2 = GATConv(hidden_channels * num_heads, hidden_channels, heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout)
        self.conv3 = GATConv(hidden_channels * num_heads, out_channels, heads=1, concat = False, dropout=dropout)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x, attention_weights1 = self.conv1(x, edge_index, return_attention_weights=True)
        x = F.elu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout, training=self.training)
        x, attention_weights2 = self.conv2(x, edge_index, return_attention_weights=True)
        x = F.elu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout, training=self.training)
        x, attention_weights3 = self.conv3(x, edge_index, return_attention_weights=True)

        #Note: When using CrossEntropyLoss, the softmax function is included in the loss function
        #out = self.softmax(x)
        return x, attention_weights1, attention_weights2, attention_weights3
```

Using this implementation, we trained a GAT on an undirected graph to perform binary classification. Then we extracted the attention weights from the last layer (attention_weights3 in the code). According to the paper on which this implementation was based (https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10903), for every pair of nodes (i,j) there should be an attention weight from node i to node j, and one attention weight from node j to node i. However, for each edge, we receive only one attention weight. Have we misunderstood what the *attention wieghts* in this implementation is?

We tried extracting the attention weights for the last layer but **it gives only one weight per edge**. Furthermore, when selecting one node and adding up the attention weights of all edges conntected to that node, the values **do not add up to 1**. If the attention weights were the normalized version described in the paper, then the attention weights for a particular node should add up to 1.